# Compare two files and print Available and NotFound

Tags: awk

I would like to compare the second field from `F11.txt` and first field from `F22.txt`. Then, print the matching cases as "Available" and non matching cases as "NotFound".

Inputs:

F11.txt

```
a,10,zzz
b,20,zzz
c,50,zzz
```

F22.txt

```
10,yyy
20,yyy
30,yyy
40,yyy
```

Have tried the below command,

```
awk -F "," 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print $0 "," (a[$2]?a[$2]:"NotFound")  }' f22.txt f11.txt
```

Got the below output:

```
a,10,zzz,10,yyy
b,20,zzz,20,yyy
c,50,zzz,NotFound
```

where to change the command to print as `Available` instead of printing the line items from `F22.txt` for match cases.

Expected output:

```
a,10,zzz,Available
b,20,zzz,Available
c,50,zzz,NotFound
```

**Update Question:**
How to include one more condition if the field $4 is not null then print Avilable & NotFound into the 4th field itself

```
example Input: F11.txt
a,10,zzz
b,20,zzz,yyy
c,50,zzz

Expected Output:
a,10,zzz,Available
b,20,zzz,yyy
c,50,zzz,NotFound
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
awk -F "," 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print $0 "," (a[$2]?"Available":"NotFound")  }' f22.txt f11.txt
```

Comment: sat, how to include one more condition if the field $4 is not null then print Avilable & NotFound into the 4th field itself
example Input:
a,10,zzz
b,20,zzz,yyy
c,50,zzz

Expected Output:
a,10,zzz,Avilable
b,20,zzz,yyy
c,50,zzz,NotFound

Comment: @AVN You store as much of `$0` as you want to print out later in the `NR==FNR` loop. Right now that's all of `$0` but if you want less store that instead.

Comment: Etan, Just now updated the question for more clarity and sample input/output, here the catch is though b,20,zzz,yyy is match case but dont want to override as "Avilable"